# Initial value problem for PDE - a definition

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, mathematical-modeling

In studying PDE theory I started with the linear one-dimensional transport equation, which basically comes from the *conservation law*,
$$ u_t + cu_x = 0,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x\in \mathbb{R},\,t>0,$$
where $u=u(t,x)$ denote a density (i.e., mass per length unit).
Keeping in mind the physical interpretation of the previous, if I add some (generic) initial condition $u(0, x) = g(x)$ I deal with an initial value problem 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_t + cu_x = 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x\in \mathbb{R},\,t>0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)\\
\\
u(0,x) = g(x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x\in \mathbb{R}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)\\
\end{matrix}\right.$$
I know this is probably stupid to ask, but **what is a rigorous definition of solution for the previous initial value problem**? My doubts come from the fact that I don't know how to treat the line $t=0$ in terms of domain of definition for a solution.

Do I need to find $u\in C^1([0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R})$ such that it satisfies both $(1)-(2)$, or just ask for a function $u\in C^1((0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R})$ such that u satisfies $(1)$ and see $(2)$ as $$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} u(t,x)=g(x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I know that if $u=u(t,x)$ satisfies $(1)$ then, by method of characteristics, $u(t,x)=f(x-ct)$ on $ (0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ for an arbitrary $f:\mathbb{R}\longmapsto \mathbb{R}$. How do I have to use de IC $u(0,x)=g(x) \,\,\,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ to conclude that $u=g(x−ct)$ in the whole $[0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: You have to find $u$ which satisfies $(1)$ and $(2)$ in the whole $\mathbb{R}\times[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Then you've determined $f(x)$. Or you would like to consider the case when $g\notin{C^{1}}$?

Comment: If $u=f(x-ct)$ on $(0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$ and also $u(0,x)=g(x) \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ then since $u$ is continuous 
$$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} u(t,x)=\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} f(x-ct)=f(x)=g(x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$ where the last equality holds for $(2)$. Then $f=g$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and so $u=g(x-ct)$ on the whole $[0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$. Is it correct?

Comment: Seems correct to me